# Linq to SQL Format Date time in One Take

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This was asked many times on stackoverflow on how to format the date time in a linq to sql expression, and the solution was always to force a compilation of the linq first using ToList() and then process the datetime using the luxury of the .ToString("hh:mm") formatting options.

But I'm trying to do it in one take and I partially succeeded, except that the code is both terrible and ugly, any shorter way to do this, assuming that the date object is a unix timestamp stored in the db, im trying to return just the timepart as *4:54 pm*.

```
            production_cycles = from p in db.ProductionCycles
                                where p.IsRunning == true
                                select new Rest.ProductionCycle {
                                    id = p.ID,
                                    name = p.Name,
                                    created = p.Created,
                                    steps = from s in p.Logs
                                            where user_permissions.Contains(s.Permission.ID)
                                            orderby s.ID ascending
                                            select new Rest.Step {
                                                created = s.Created,
                                                created_label = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           0

                          ).Value.Hour.ToString() 
                          + ":" +
                            DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", (DateTime)SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", s.Created + (offset * 60 * 60), new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))),
                           0

                          ).Value.Minute.ToString()                         


                          ,
                                                username = s.User.Name,
```

Comment: I would put the ugly code in a separate method rather than cluttering you linq.   The unix timestamp starts in 1970 while windows starts in 1900. so you could just add the time from Jan 1, 1900 to Jan 1, 1970 to the unix time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this out :

```
var baseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
production_cycles = from p in db.ProductionCycles
    where p.IsRunning == true
    select new Rest.ProductionCycle
    {
        id = p.ID,
        name = p.Name,
        created = p.Created,
        steps = from s in p.Logs
            where user_permissions.Contains(s.Permission.ID)
            orderby s.ID ascending
            select new Rest.Step
            {
                created = s.Created,
                created_label = DbFunctions.DiffHours(baseDate, s.Created).ToString + ":" + DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(baseDate, s.Created).ToString + ":" +DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(baseDate, s.Created).ToString

                ////// the rest as usual

            },
    };
```