# Processing Data After Linq to SQL Call

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've been using LINQ to SQL for a while, and most of the time I end up creating a complex linq expressions using SQLFunctions and DbEntities classes to mimic functions such as toString or DateTime formating (e.g. [Linq to SQL Format Date time in One Take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093660/linq-to-sql-format-date-time-in-one-take)) not available in Linq to SQL.

I always thought that this is much cleaner than forcing query execution using ToList() and then using linq again but this time with objects with all the available functions. My questions is, which is a better approach, try to stuff everything in one Linq to SQL expression with efforts to format the data and everything, or go the easy way and just extract the data in one step and then process it using ForEach on the resulting list from the first query.

Comment: can you provide an example? you shouldn't have to be rewriting `ToString()` or date time formatting if you select the fields, `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` the results, then do your normal `ToString()` or `string.Format()` kinds of things.

Comment: really the only time i use those type of function is if it will help me prevent a large portion of data coming back that i dont need.. like `(int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", a.Date) == 1`.  if it doesnt affect the number of records returned i just `.ToList()` first

Comment: Make sure you do not return more records than necessary from the database (you filtering belongs there). Anything else can be done in your ForEach. Pretty much as @user5103147 explains.